# Prolog, gender with if_then_else

Tags: if-statement, prolog, family-tree

I would like to say that if he is a father he is a male else is a female

```
father(pedro-i,beatriz(1347)).
father(pedro-i,joão(1349)).
father(pedro-i,dinis(1354)).
father(pedro-i,joão_grão_mestre_da_ordem_de_avis).
mother(constança(1320),luis).
mother(constança(1320),maria(1342)).


% I want to say that if is the father then is male else is a female

IF_then_else(X,Y,Z) :- father(X,Y),male.
IF_then_else(X,Y,Z) :- female.
```

Answer (score 1):

A first remark: *predicates* and *functors* start with a lowercase letter, not an uppercase: uppercases are used for *variables*.

You seem to miss the point that predicates in Prolog **do not return a value**. They can only *succeed*, or *fail* (in that sense they "return" a boolean). The way to provide (non-boolean) output is by using *unification*.

Here you can do this by putting the literal in the head like:

```
if_then_else(X,Y,male) :- father(X,Y).
if_then_else(X,Y,female).
```

But now there is **another problem**: Prolog *backtracks*. So it means that *even if the first clause succeeds*, it will try the second clause. So `pedro-i` will both be `male` and `female`. You can solve this problem by putting a *guard* on the second clause that says that the clause succeeds if Prolog cannot prove that there is a `father(X,Y)` relation. Something like:

```
if_then_else(X,Y,male) :- father(X,Y).
if_then_else(X,Y,female) :- \+ father(X,Y).
```

But this can result in a computationally expensive problem: it is possible that it takes a long time to prove that there is a `father(X,Y).` relation, and if there is no such relation, failing to prove so will take even more time (because Prolog needs to check all branches). It might even result in an infinite loop to do so. In this case you can use a *cut* (`!`). If you reach a cut, Prolog will not attempt to find results in the following clauses of the predicate. So you can write:

```
if_then_else(X,Y,male) :- father(X,Y), !.
if_then_else(X,Y,female).
```

Alternatively you can use Prolog's [if-then-else structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10878127/67579) and use *explicit* unification:

```
if_then_else(X,Y,Z) :-
    (  father(X,Y)
    -> Z = male
    ;  Z = female
    ).
```